# DateTime.ParseExact Incorrect Format Specifier

Tags: c#, datetime, format

The following code

```
var test = "2016-10-26_02-48-17-PM";
var testTime = DateTime.ParseExact(test, 
                                   "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-tt", 
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

throws the exception;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

when executed.  What did I miss?

Comment: Try change HH to hh..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the 24 hour hour specifier "HH" with the AM/PM string "tt".

If you have your time in 24 hour clock format (00 - 23) then you don't need the AM/PM designation. However, if your times are 12 hour format with AM/PM you'll need to use the "hh" hour specifier.

This:

```
var test = "2016-10-26_02-48-17";
var testTime = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or this:

```
var test = "2016-10-26_02-48-17-PM";
var testTime = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

should work

Comment: Thanks, I went the other way by keeping `tt` and replacing `HH` with `hh`.  Principle's the same though.